# SQL Where clause conditional assignment based on another parameter

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I need to generate a report where the user can choose All Issues, Open Issues, or Closed issues in a radio button. In my view I have a isClosed bit column. If I didn't have the All Issues radio box I'd just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
WHERE isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords
```

However I need to remove the `isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords` condition when the `@ViewAllRecords = true`. How would I do this?

Comment: Smacks head. Apparently its one of those days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
WHERE @ViewAllRecords OR isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords
```

Comment: I try this and query builder says "Invalid column name true" and then it changes it to  `(isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords) OR
                   (ProjectID = @RequestedProjectID) AND 
                   (true = @ViewAllRecords)` but still errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from MyView
WHERE isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords
OR @ViewAllRecords
```

And set `@ViewAllRecords` parameters to true when user selects "All Issues" in the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
(@ViewAllRecords = false AND isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords)
OR 
(@ViewAllRecords = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you all rows with `isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords`. If `@ViewAllRecords = true` then it will return all rows and ignore `isClosed`.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
WHERE isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords
   OR @ViewAllRecords = true
```

Comment: for some reason it wouldn't equate true as a boolean, but after I set it as a string and did = 'true' it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (@ViewAllRecords <> true AND isClosed = @ViewClosedRecords)
```